# Bookmark Button with core data in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

Question:- I am having problem while deleting a row from core data. Whenever I perform the delete function, The values in the row are changed to 0 but the row still exist in Core database. How can I completely remove the row in below written code?

I have a `tableView` showing some list, each cell has a button with grey bookmark image as default.

When I click on `bookmarkBtn`, the button image is changed to blue image and the data is stored by coreData. After clicking it again, `bookmarkBtn` again changes to grey image and the entry in core data is supposed to be deleted.

```
 //Code:- **when bookmarkBtn is clicked.**
 @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
      let position: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
      let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: position)!
      sender.tag = indexPath.row
      let cell: TableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    // print("Favorite button tapped")
      if sender.isSelected != true
         {
          cell.bookmarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "bookmark_blue"), for: UIControlState.normal);
          sender.isSelected = true;
          saveItem(itemToSave:sender.tag)
          self.bookmarkArrState.replaceObject(at: (indexPath.row), with:1);
         } 
        else
        {
         cell.bookmarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "bookmark_grey" ), for: UIControlState.normal);
         sender.isSelected = false;
         removeData(itemToDelete: sender.tag)
         self.bookmarkArrState.replaceObject(at: (indexPath.row), with:0)
       }

   }

  //Code:- **Saving values in CoreData**
  func saveItem(itemToSave: Int){
     let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
     //**Note:** Here we are providing the entityName **`Entity`** that we have added in the model
     let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AddedBookmark", in: context)
    let myItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    myItem.setValue(itemToSave, forKey: "indexNo")
    do {
        try context.save()
        }
    catch{
        print("There was an error in saving data")  
    }
}

 //**Code:- Deleting Data when bookmarkBtn is clicked again**
 func removeData(itemToDelete: Int)
{
    let mngdCntxt = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    //**Note:** Here we are providing the entityName **`Entity`** that we have added in the model
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AddedBookmark", in: mngdCntxt)
    let myItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: mngdCntxt)


    if let dataAppDelegatde = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
       let mngdCntxt = dataAppDelegatde.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AddedBookmark")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "indexNo = %i", Int(itemToDelete))
        print("item selected :-\(itemToDelete)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        do{
            var result = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest)

            print(result.count)
            print(fetchRequest)


            if result.count > 0{
                for object in result
                {
                    print(object)
                    mngdCntxt.performAndWait {
                        mngdCntxt.delete(result[0] as! NSManagedObject)
                        mngdCntxt.refreshAllObjects()  
                    }
                }
            }
            do {
                try mngdCntxt.save()
            }
            catch{
                print("There was an error in saving data")
            }
        }   
        catch{
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `for object in result`, you're deleting `result[0]` not `object`? You don't actually need for loop, just `deletedObjects(result)`?

Comment: @zcui93 There can be duplicates, so for that I am taking all the duplicate object in result and passing in for loop to delete one by one.

Comment: `result[0]` means you're always deleting the same one?

Comment: **Check this thread** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990426/how-to-delete-row-in-table-view-core-data-swift-3/48018009#48018009

Comment: @SachinRaut I am deleting the values in core data and not removing the cell on button click. And the above link shows how to delete the cell by sliding it to left and removing the value from core data, which I have already executed in another module and have the code ready for that.